# Buttons and inputs are not displayed on Modal

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

Buttons are inputs fields are not getting displayed on modal inside .aspx page but labels are visible

```html
<div class="modal inmodal" id="mdl_filter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute;">
        <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                <div class="modal-header" style="height: 55px; padding-top: 10px">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Filter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="space-10"></div>
                        <div id="filter_form" class="wizard-big filter_form">
                            <div class="step-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">                                       
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>By Number</label>
                                            <input id="txt_filter_number" name="txt_filter_number" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" />
                                        </div>                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Output (missing buttons and input fields):
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `.modal-footer` div is inside the `.modal-body` div.  The [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) has an example that shows the footer div **outside** of the body div

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same html for the modal popup that you reported and its working perfectly. I think you are missing css or other css are hiding your modal elements. have a look here:

```js
    function showModal()
    {
        $('#mdl_filter').modal('show');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" id="btnShow" onclick="showModal();" value="Show Modal"/>
   <div class="modal inmodal" id="mdl_filter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute;">
        <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                <div class="modal-header" style="height: 55px; padding-top: 10px">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Filter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="space-10"></div>
                        <div id="filter_form" class="wizard-big filter_form">
                            <div class="step-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">                                       
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>By Number</label>
                                            <input id="txt_filter_number" name="txt_filter_number" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" />
                                        </div>                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```